how can I save a video to local computer storage, from web interface of whatsapp?
how can I  save a video to local computer storage, from web interface of whatsapp?
Below is an image from whatsapp web interface

The little wide rectangle is an image
If I right click that then no problem there is even an option "save image as"

But if I right click the video
There isn't really any recognition that it's a video

e.g. I get a print option.
There is a "save as" option, but that just tries to save it as "WhatsApp.html"

Simply click on the video, and in the frame that opens to play the video, the Download button is available.
Like the image below:

